# вызывать определенный массив из метода

Tags: php

Есть функция валидации полей, для каждого поля свое правило в массивах, как эти массивы определить к примеру в метод `rules` и с него потом доставать нужный массив?

```
$arr_name = [
  'required' => true,
  'name' => $_POST['name'],
  'field_name' => 'Название',
  'min' => 2,
  'max' => 10,
];
$arr_description = [
  'required' => true,
  'name' => $_POST['description'],
  'field_name' => 'Описание',
  'min' => 3,
  'max' => 15,
];
$arr_text = [
  'required' => false,
  'name' => $_POST['text'],
  'field_name' => 'текст',

  'max' => 15,
];
```

Comment: сложите в общий массив правил `$rules = ['name' => [...] , 'text' => [....]]` да доставайте, в чем проблема то? или не используйте "переменные переменных"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно понять вопрос. Если Вам нужно это, то рад был помочь

```
<?php
class MyRulesBox
{
    const RULES = [
        'name' => [
            'required' => true,
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'field_name' => 'Название',
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 10,
        ],
        'description' => [
                'required' => true,
                'name' => $_POST['description'],
                'field_name' => 'Описание',
                'min' => 3,
                'max' => 15,
            ],
        'text' => [
            'required' => false,
            'name' => $_POST['text'],
            'field_name' => 'текст',
            'max' => 15,
        ]
    ];

    public static function rules($needArray) {
        return self::RULES[$needArray] ?? [];
    }
}

// Получить значения используя метод rules
$arrName = MyRulesBox::rules('name');
$arrDescription = MyRulesBox::rules('description');
$arrText = MyRulesBox::rules('text');
```